# Why rails added dot to URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

Question:

Why rails added dot before name, in URL?

**Exemple:**

exemple.com/.category1 
 exemple.com/.category2

**Code :**

*models/blog.rb*

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :title
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
Exemple::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :blogs
  root :to => "blog#index"
end
```

*views/layouts/application.html.erb*

```
<% Blog.all.each do |category| %>
   <%= link_to category.title, root_path(category.name) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What output are you expecting here?

Comment: You don't seem to have any routes that would respond to a URL like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails named routes accept some optional parameters. One of them is `(.:format)`. The full signature of `root_path`.

`root_path("xml")` is the same as `root_path(:format => "xml")` which will resolve to `"/.xml"` or in your case `example.com/.category1`.